# C++ default argument constructor vs inline initialisation priority

Tags: c++

Is the variable here 1 or 2 and is this compiler or standard dependent?

```
class foo {
    int val = 1;

    foo(int bar = 2) : val(bar) {}
}
```

Comment: It'll be 2 if you don't pass anything to the constructor.

Comment: It's 2. The ` = 1` is redundant in this situation. The only way `val` will equal 1 is if that is the value explicitly passed to the constructor.

Comment: The fact that this uses an initialiser list is incidental. It's the same as if you'd have written `{ foo = bar; }`. Additionally, the fact you're using C++11 is not a relevant concern here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `2` unless you provide a different value when calling the constructor.
See [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) concerning non-static data member initialisation:

> If a member has a default member initializer and also appears in the
>   member initialization list in a constructor, the default member
>   initializer is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

this here : `foo(int bar = 2)`  is called default argument,

and allows you to call a function without providing that argument.

How?

if you do:

`foo(100)`  then **val** is initialized with 100

but if you ommit the parameter

`foo( )`  then **val** is initialized with 2

at the end, that declaration makes this init superfluous:

```
int val = 1;
```